# Cookie not deleted when browser is closed - Only in chrome

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I am setting a cookie like below:

```
setCookie('hp_popup_exec', 1, 0);
```

I have read that if the cookie if set with a lifetime `0`, when the broswer closes, it is destroyed but this is not happening.

When I open the browser again the cookie is still here.

**How can it be removed when browser closes ?**

Comment: Could https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124044/setcookie-with-expire-0-does-not-expire-after-the-browser-closes be the problem?

Comment: @NigelRen Unfortunately no. It is "open in a new tab" in my chrome settings. But in firefox it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue just by updating my chrome.